# Why does self made(.NET) Worker Service as Windows Service give "Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly" while starting the serivce?

Tags: windows-services, worker-service

I created a worker service in .NET and I planned to deploy that service to windows machine so I created it as windows service.
When I started deploying the service (using sc.exe), everything went smoothly until I tried to start up the service and I got error: "Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly".
It did start up in my dev machine so the problem must be related with the target machine.

Answers from "googling" didn't help me much and were kind of disperse.
What might cause this error?

Comment: Looks like the title is the question and the body is the answer. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: That is correct. How should I post it in here properly? As I couldn't find any article with similar topic I wanted to share my findings.

Comment: Change your title to something that summarizes the problem, change the body to contain all the details of the question, and post an answer with your solution. See this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday) for a great example of answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was simple. My target machine was missing the directory that my service was trying to use. I added the proper directory and folder into my dev machine and the error was gone.